# Finding the probability density function (pdf) for a two variable 'function'

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

Asking rather basic question.

Say we have two parameters:

$x,y$ with a pdf $X(x),Y(y)$.

I want to  calculate the pdf for a third parameter say: $z$ which is defined by:

$z=f(x,y)$

What would the pdf function $Z(z)$ would look like?

Sorry if that's embarrassing

Best regards anyone who spends time on this :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately **there is no general method that can give you $Z$ from $X,Y$**.

If there is a variable transformation $f$ that is **bijective**, and such, **invertable**, then there does exist a formula. However, since $z = f(x,y)$ reduces the dimensionality of the input space from $2$ to $1$, $f$ is likely not invertable.

If you don't mind, I'd like to change your notation for the p.d.f. of $x$ to $f_x$, so we can use $F_x$ for its c.d.f.

So the method is the following:

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$, with $x := (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y := (y_1,\dots,y_n)$, and $x$ having joint p.d.f. $f_x$ and joint c.d.f. $F_x$, then $\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}\mathbb{P}(y_1 \le a_1,\dots,y_n \le a_n) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}\mathbb{P}(f(x) \le (a_1,\dots,a_n)) = \\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}\mathbb{P}(x \le f^{-1}(a_1,\dots,a_n)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i} F_x(f^{-1}(a_1,\dots,a_n)) = \\ = f_x(f^{-1}(a_1,\dots,a_n))\cdot \left(\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial a_i}\right)(a_1,\dots,a_n)$$

where the derivative of the inverse of $f$ is often called the Hessian matrix with elements

$$H_{i,j}(a_1,\dots,a_n) = \left(\left(\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial a_i}\right)(a_1,\dots,a_n)\right)_j$$

So the p.d.f. of $y$ in this case is

$$f_y(a) = f_x(f^{-1}(a))[H_1(a) \cdots H_n(a)]$$

where $H_k(a)$ is the $k$'th row of the Hessian matrix evaluated at $a$.

Comment: Wow really expected this was trivia. By the way, I just have read a paper that gets posterior distribution (from gaussian regression ) of certain parameters (3 in the number). Then they apply a formula that takes these 3 parameters and give a 4th one (say M) and they show the posterior pdf of M without mentioning much info. So I thought it was trivia.  Gonna read the answer and comment again

Comment: From what I saw online,  Bijective function means it's also monotonic strictly wherever it is defined. So it's not the case for me.
Also are we sure that there is not a more simpler way? (for example in binned-pdf probabilities I think it   seems easy to derive it by summing and calculationg X(x)*Y(x) and then binning the results

Comment: There might be simpler methods for specific cases, for example, if $Z = X + Y$, then the p.d.f. of $Z$ if the convolution of the p.d.f. of $X$ and $Y$, even though $f(X,Y)=X+Y$ is not invertable. However, without knowing *anything* about $f$, or the initial distribution of $X,Y$, we can't say much.

Comment: This is what I meant by "there is no **general** method". There are plenty of methods for individual cases.

Comment: Bijective does not imply monotonicity. In fact it doesn't even imply continuity. For example, take the following bijection of $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$: write up the full decimal expression of the input number, and swap every odd digit with every even digit before and after the decimal point. This is bijective (there is a one-to-one correspondence between the inputs and outputs), but it isn't monotonic, and it certainly isn't continuous.

Comment: The only way of a bijective function not being monotonic, is not being continuous.  If because it can cover the "non monotonic" gaps "later" in that parameter's range. But in the pdfs of the paper and mine, every pdf is monotonic and continuous

Comment: That sounds true. However, the reverse isn't. A monotonic continuous function isn't necessarily bijective. It has to be surjective as well. (It has to cover the entire output space.)

Comment: yeah, but at any rate, it's said that the posterior distribution for two parameters is  freely used to compute the posterior distribution for a third parameter. I'm pretty sure there has to be a way, cuz it's not even explained how (in the paper, so it has to be trivia).

Comment: If the prior is known (the exact distribution $X$ and $Y$), as well as $f$, then you can write up the integral that $\mathbb{P}(z\le t)=\mathbb{P}(f(x,y)\le t)$, and calculate it directly.

Comment: But this is what I'm asking how. The exact distribution of X and Y is given by the known pdfs

Comment: There is really not a more general formula I can give. You need to manipulate the expression $f(x,y) \le t$ inside the body of $\mathbb{P}$ to see how and when $f$ can be less than a given $t$. I highly suggest looking at this example, and the specific methods they use for the case of $z = x+y$: [Distribution calculating using convolution](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_1_2_sums_random_variables.php)

Comment: So for example if $z =x+y$, then $Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(t)Y(z-t)dt$. But this was concluded from a probability thought process, no any formula.

Comment: And even for a different simple function: $z = xy$, we don't actually know the general formula, only in some cases ($x,y$ are independent, $x,y$ are from certain specific distributions, etc.) [Distribution of the product of two random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables)

Comment: so what you said in the previous comment regarding $P(f(x,y)<t)$ is not directly calculated?

Comment: In the case for $f(x,y)=x+y$, it *can* be directly calculated. In most cases, it cannot.